# iTextSharp v. 5.5.3 to 5.5.6 - error flattening TextField

Tags: itext, textfield

I have a problem. I using iTextSharp v. (5.5.3 to 5.5.6).
I have one file PDF and 1 page. 
On the side I have 4 TextField (rotation: 0, 90, 180, 270) and one red polygon
My page rotation is set 270

I can flatten page

In code, I set

```
stamper.AnnotationFlattening = true;
stamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

After flattening my 2 TextField are rotated incorrectly

Image 1 of the original PDF:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2 with error:

[image]

The PDF:

http://www.pdf-archive.com/2015/08/20/wyslac/

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. You can do so via a public share (e.g. on google drive or dropbox) and post the link here.

Comment: Add link to file PDF

Comment: http://www.pdf-archive.com/2015/08/20/wyslac/

Comment: Does the work-around I mentioned in my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks

Comment: If an answer to your question works for you, please accept it (click on the tick on the left of the answer), so people coming across your question later can recognize that.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in iText(Sharp) when flattening form fields with existing appearances rotated by means of their **Matrix** attribute if `pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances` is `true`.

The original

[image: Original top of page]

after flattening with `GenerateAppearances == true` looks like this:

[image: GenerateAppearances == true]

### Workaround

As the document already has appearance streams, you can switch off `GenerateAppearances`:

```
stamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = false;
stamper.AnnotationFlattening = true;
stamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

The result you get now:

[image: GenerateAppearances == false]

### The issue

If `GenerateAppearances == true`, then iTextSharp (when flattening forms) first looks whether a field already has an appearance. If the field has one, iTextSharp only attempts to neatly fit the existing appearance into the rectangle of the form field. Unfortunately it (a) ignores the existing form field **Matrix** entry and (b) replaces it with a new matrix doing the fitting. If the appearance was rotated by means of its **Matrix**, that rotation is lost and instead the value is stretched to fit into the falsely oriented rectangle.

```
if (acroFields.GenerateAppearances) {
    if (appDic == null || as_n == null) {
        [...]
    } else if (as_n.IsStream()) {
        PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) as_n;
        PdfArray bbox = stream.GetAsArray(PdfName.BBOX);
        PdfArray rect = merged.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
        if (bbox != null && rect != null) {
            float rectWidth = rect.GetAsNumber(2).FloatValue - rect.GetAsNumber(0).FloatValue;
            float bboxWidth = bbox.GetAsNumber(2).FloatValue - bbox.GetAsNumber(0).FloatValue;
            float rectHeight = rect.GetAsNumber(3).FloatValue - rect.GetAsNumber(1).FloatValue;
            float bboxHeight = bbox.GetAsNumber(3).FloatValue - bbox.GetAsNumber(1).FloatValue;
            float widthCoef = Math.Abs(bboxWidth != 0 ? rectWidth / bboxWidth : float.MaxValue);
            float heightCoef = Math.Abs(bboxHeight != 0 ? rectHeight / bboxHeight : float.MaxValue);

            if (widthCoef != 1 || heightCoef != 1)
            {
                NumberArray array = new NumberArray(widthCoef, 0, 0, heightCoef, 0, 0);
                stream.Put(PdfName.MATRIX, array);
                MarkUsed(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*(`PdfStamperImp` method `FlatFields`)*

### The background

The reason why iTextSharp ignores the appearance **Matrix** is that appearance generation in the course of form filling is not supposed to use such matrix values:

> For non-rich text fields, the appearance stream—which, like all appearance streams, is a form XObject—has the contents of its form dictionary initialized as follows:
>
> - The resource dictionary (**Resources**) shall be created using resources from the interactive form dictionary’s **DR** entry (see Table 218).
> - The lower-left corner of the bounding box (**BBox**) is set to coordinates (0, 0) in the form coordinate system. The box’s top and right coordinates are taken from the dimensions of the annotation rectangle (the **Rect** entry in the widget annotation dictionary).
> - All other entries in the appearance stream’s form dictionary are set to their default values (see 8.10, “Form XObjects”).
>
> *(section 12.7.3.3 "Variable Text" of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

This means for the **Matrix**:

> **Matrix** array *(Optional)* An array of six numbers specifying the form matrix, which maps form space into user space (see 8.3.4, "Transformation Matrices"). Default value: the identity matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0].
>
> *(Table 95 – Additional Entries Specific to a Type 1 Form Dictionary - in section 8.10.2 "Form Dictionaries", [ibidem](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus, form field appearance streams created during fill-in according to the specification, can be assumed to have a an identity **Matrix** value, and no rotation.

So the issue in iTextSharp actually merely reflects the assumption that form field appearances are generated due to form fill-in.