# Signatures are being rotated when a landscape PDF is flatten using iText 5.5

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a landscape PDf document that looks like this
[image]

When I try to flatten some specific fields using ***iText Sharp v5.5***, the result I got is this:
[image]

The code used for flattening is as follows:

```
        //read the file as byte array
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(b);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, ms);
            stamper.AnnotationFlattening = true;
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;                    
    // loop through the required fields to flatten, flatten specific fields
            foreach (string name in fieldNames2Flatten)
            {
                stamper.PartialFormFlattening(name);
            }

            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
    }
```

Please advise

Comment: Apparently iText 5 flattening does not take all factors into account that might cause a rotation. As there are multiple ways to rotate an appearance, im not sure what is ignored.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137680/1729265 - to be sure, we'd need the PDF in question for analysis.